# web console - grab all links - HELP needed

Tags: browser, console, web

I found this useful code

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("a");
var myarray = []
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
var nametext = x[i].textContent;
var cleantext = nametext.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
var cleanlink = x[i].href;
myarray.push([cleantext,cleanlink]);
};
function make_table() {
    var table = '<table><thead><th>Name</th><th>Links</th></thead><tbody>';
   for (var i=0; i<myarray.length; i++) {
            table += '<tr><td>'+ myarray[i][0] + '</td><td>'+myarray[i][1]+'</td></tr>';
    };
 
    var w = window.open("");
w.document.write(table); 
}
make_table()
```

When you add this to the web browser console - it opens up a new webpage with all weblinks with names

- however some of the names are shortned.

is there a way to edit it so it shows the entire text name for that link

Comment: The `Name` data wraps to a new line. Are you sure they're being truncated?

Comment: I just checked on public sites and its working fine,

looks like it is having issues on our internal PRTG site

I will close :)